# Find the value of P(2014) given some properties about this polynomial...

Tags: polynomials

A polynomial P satisfies the following criterion:

1. It's coefficients are integers.
2. For all real $(a, b, c, d)$ we have $(P(a) + P(b))(P(c) + P(d)) = P(ac - bd) + P(ad + bc)$.

Determine all possible values of $P(2014)$.

My logic:

Clearly $2014$ is not a convenient value to find, so we must begin searching for possible identities of the polynomial by plugging in values, seeing what they output, and thus deducing how the polynomial behaves given certain values.

Set $(a, b, c, d) = 0$, getting

$4P(0)^2 = 2P(0)$, which, dividing by $2$, yields

$2P(0)^2 = P(0)$, and thus $P(0) = 0$, which tells us that there is no constant term and the polynomial identities we're after involve only variables and their coefficients. I write the polynomial, say degree $n$, as follows:

$Ex^n + Fx^{n-1} + Gx^{n-2} + ...$

From here on I'm kind of at a loss, because I don't know where to go or what to do. I've found the constant value, but anything else seems pretty far-fetched.

Thanks!

Comment: Please use LaTeX (MathJax) to write math.

Comment: I don't know how.

Comment: I'll edit your post for you momentarily. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/463/put-a-link-to-a-tutorial-on-the-tex-in-the-faq/464#464.

Comment: @JimmyK4542, ah, I didn't consider that. Therefore, the constant could either be 0, or 1/2.

Comment: ^EDIT: I realized my comment was moot since $P(0) = 1/2$ isn't possible if $P(x)$ has all integer coefficients.

Comment: By Gauss' Lemma, wouldn't this be a valid value though, because given that a linear factor of a polynomial can be expressed in rational numbers, it can be multiplied such that it can be expressed in integers as well, leading to an integer constant?

Comment: If $P(x) = a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ has all integer coefficients, then $P(0) = a_0$ is an integer.

Comment: Well, it looks like George took the liberty to edit the post for you. LaTeX is worth learning not only to ask questions on this site but for mathematical purposes later on. I suggest it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting $(a,b,c,d) = (0,0,0,0)$ yields $4P(0)^2 = 2P(0)$, i.e. $P(0) = 0$ or $P(0) = \frac{1}{2}$.

However, since all the coefficients of $P(x)$ are integers, $P(0)$ must be an integer. Hence, $P(0) = 0$.

Then, setting $(a,b,c,d) = (x,0,y,0)$ yields $P(x)P(y) = P(xy)$ for all reals $x,y$.

Also, setting $(a,b,c,d) = (0,x,0,y)$ yields $P(x)P(y) = P(-xy)$ for all reals $x,y$.

Thus, $P(x)$ is an even polynomial. If $P(x) \not\equiv 0$, then $P(\alpha) > 0$ for some $\alpha > 0$.

Hence, $f(x) = \ln P(e^x)$ is a solution to [Cauchy's functional equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$, and is continuous at $x = \ln \alpha$. Therefore, $f(x) = nx$ for some constant $n$. This gives $P(x) = x^n$, so $n$ must be an even non-negative integer.

Setting $(a,b,c,d) = (x,1,1,1)$ yields $2(x^n+1) = (x-1)^n+(x+1)^n$. If $n > 2$ then the $x^{2}$ coefficient of the left side is $0$ but the $x^{2}$ coefficient of the right side is $2\dbinom{n}{2}$, a contradiction. If $n = 0$ we get $4 = 2$, a contradiction. Hence, the only possible value of $n$ is $n = 2$.

Clearly, $P(x) = x^2$ works. Hence the only solutions are $P(x) = 0$ and $P(x) = x^2$.

Therefore, the only possible values of $P(2014)$ are $0$ and $2014^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from $P(0)=0$, now set $b=d=0$ to get $P(a)P(c)=P(ac)$ and $a=c=0$ to get $P(b)P(d)=P(-bd)$ so $P$ must be even.  $a=d=1, b=c=0$ gives $P(1)^2=P(1)$, so $P(1)=0,1$  $a=b=c=d=1$ gives $4P(1)^2=P(2)$ and generally $a=b=c=d$ gives $4P(a)^2=P(2a^2)$  It sure looks like the only choices are $P(x)=0$ or $P(x)=x^2$ though I haven't proven that. If we plug this in we get $$(P(a)+P(b))(P(c)+P(d))=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)\\=a^2c^2+b^2c^2+a^2d^2+b^2d^2\\=(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2\\=P(ac-bd)+P(ad+bc)$$  So $P(x)=x^2$ works